# Get info from API

Tags: ruby, api, sinatra-activerecord

I got a really tricky API where I'm getting some books info from. I would need to get the cover image when available though but I can't get it.

This is how my API looks like:

[image: API]

And this is my code to get till 'cover'. I can't select though the large cover.

```
@infos = HTTParty.get("http://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:#{params[:isbn]}&jscmd=data&format=json")
@data = @infos["ISBN:#{params[:isbn]}"]
@cover = @data['cover]
```

As you can see I'm using Ruby. Any help guys?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow! I see that you've asked your first question, allow me to help you. Please proofread your question to make it legible to readers. Also, don't link your code, post it. Links can die, so the stack doesn't appreciate it when you create this sort of dependency. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@infos = HTTParty.get("https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:#{params[:isbn]}&jscmd=data&format=json")
@data = @infos["ISBN:#{params[:isbn]}"]
@cover = @data['cover']["large"]
```

Comment: Based on what you've posted it absolutely should work.

Comment: I know.. but it doesn't.. I've been going on this for the last 3 days..cause I needed it for a project...but doesn't display anything(in my erb page I put the image code and inside of that the ruby tag with @cover.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit familiar with APIs.
Though I can't tell you EXACTLY what to do in terms of code, I *can* tell you that what you need to do is download Postman from the Google Chrome store and ctrl c ctrl v your link. This will then parse whatever code on that site into JSON format. You should then be able to see where your photo is located and then access it from there.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions that the poster could try out without downloading another software?

Comment: Not as of now, @MatthewCliatt . However, the software I mentioned helps to locate where in the link a particular element that you are looking to use is. There's more than one way to skin a cat ;)